# iphone6s called wrong UIControlEvent method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicontrolevents

I wrote a simple demo to show my issue.The button need to be added two touch events:drag and touch.

```
UIButton * btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(300, 100, 100, 100);
btn1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(stretchBtnDragMoving:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];
[btn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(stretchBtnDragEnded:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

And then,

```
- (void)stretchBtnDragMoving:(UIControl *)control withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"moving");
}
- (void)stretchBtnDragEnded:(UIControl *)control withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"end or in");
}
```

When I touched the button in iPhone6s/6s plus like normal time,both of the methods be called.
But when I touched the button very light, only the second method be called.
When I used iPhone6/6 plus,iPad and other devices,however I touched the button,only the second method be called.

Comment: I would guess different sensitivity on what is considered a drag.

Comment: 3D touch definitely changes certain way of iOS capturing your touch

Comment: But how can I avoid the different sensitivity.Do you have some nice methods. @Avi

Comment: @zcui93 I closed the 3D touch,but the problem is still exist.

Comment: I think it's a mistake to use both events.  If you were tracking the touches yourself, you could have your own threshold for what is considered a drag versus a touch.  With the control events, you are stuck with whatever Apple implements.